# displaying row details in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am simply trying to show detail view page from table page

I have set up displaying list of pages via another function like this and works fine

```
> <a href="< ? php echo
> $ this -> url(array('controller'=>'page','action'=>'detail',
> 'id'=>$page->id));? >"> < ? php echo
> $this->escape($page->title);? ></a>
```

In my controller i added

> ```
> public function detailAction()
> {
>         $id = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
>         $page = new Application_Model_DbTable_Pages();
>         $this->view->myVar = $page->getPage($id);
> }
> ```

and in view

```
>  <?php  print_r($this->myvar) ?>
```

This list

I just see blank page, how can i show detail page ?

Comment: have you tried with enabling errors & warning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php  print_r($this->myVar) ?>
```

insted of myvar --> myVar. That is how You called Your variable in the action method.

Comment: I thought php is not case sensetive